# Popup application under citrix

Tags: window, citrix, xenapp

We are planning to develop an application that will run as a windows service that reads a DB for entries on a timer interval basis.  whenever an entry is found the service opens shows a popup in the system try, something like lync or ocs.
My question is whether it is possible to deploy the windows service and the popup application under citrix xen app?

Man thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, but you need to keep in mind how those popups will be consumed by a XenApp user. In particular how is the popup app going to get started?

If your users are using published desktops then you can put your popup app in the startup folder of your users so it will always launch and be running and everything will work fine. However if your users are running published apps then you should have the popup app published and get your users to run this published app.